# __RequestVerificationToken not sent correctly with axios 0.17.1 and MVC 3/4/5

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, axios, antiforgerytoken

I eliminated jQuery from the project in favor of axios, but when I try to validate the __RequestVerificationToken, the controller responds with:

> The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present

I see that the data is sent in json format and with jquery as form data.

Is there any way for the Controller to detect the json format or do I need to serialize the data before sending it?

```
axios({
      url: '/api/controller/method',
      data: {
        __RequestVerificationToken,
        otherData
      },
      method: 'post'
    })
```

Comment: The payload gets flat into one - that is why. I am after this problem now. I will post the solution when I have it.

Comment: Thanks @Ognyan Dimitrov, I published the solution that we found with my team, I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We add a config file for axios and add a plugin ["qs"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs) to stringify the query.

```
import qs from 'qs'
import axios from 'axios'
import fd from '../FormDataBuilder'

axios.defaults.headers['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest'
axios.defaults.paramsSerializer = p => qs.stringify(p, { allowDots: true })
axios.defaults.transformRequest = [d => typeof d === 'object' ? d.formdata ? fd(d) : qs.stringify(d, { allowDots: true }) : d]

export default axios
```

The FormDataBuilder is a function for the case of "formdata" forms.

Now the server receive the token correctly.

Comment: I've been using Vue.js, Axios, and Asp.Net MVC for about a week.  I can't figure out how to pass the @HTML.AntiForgeryToken from my Razor page through to the Vue App and then to the Axios post requesting data.  Being a noob, the above makes very little sense, yet I think the germ of my answer is in there somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Add [qs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs) to your project (npm install qs --save)

in your .chtml :

```
<div id="token">@Html.AntiForgeryToken()</div>
```

in your component vue.js :

at the start:

```
import qs from 'qs'
import axios from "axios"
```

in the function:

```
let token = document.querySelector('token, input').getAttribute('value');   

axios.post( "/api/controller/method", qs.stringify({ '__RequestVerificationToken': token}));
```